# Does anybody know if someone had integrated libsegfault.so and gdbserver in order to get gdb attached on the fly to a crashed program?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, glibc

It's mentioned in http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2007-06/msg00360.html before.
But no one seemed to have actually implemented this kind of idea.
Is there any obstacles for realizing this?

My requirements are the following:

1. Being able to plugin to any elf binary executable (ex. by using LD_PRELOAD)
2. The binary may be a multithreaded executable
3. The binary may link to a library that contain main function
4. This should work in various cpu architecture other than x86 (MIPS, ARM, PPC at least)

So if there's already a solution like this, I wanted a link, but if there isn't yet, I wanted to know why it's not already implemented as a wheel.
It might be just that no one didn't needed it... but I think this is quite useful to prepare as a standard.

Any technical or political issue other than just putting it together code is wanted.

Comment: If you already have a segfault core file, you can attach the gdb or gdbserver to the core file and get the debug info.

If you don't but you know how to reproduce the crash, you can attach the pid and watch it segfault.

How/what is this going to help debugging?

Comment: I suppose the idea is that you don't have the overhead of having gdb[server] attached until the program actually crashes, and that looking at a live image can be more enlightening than just a core dump.  (I don't agree, but I can understand the sentiment.)  More problematically, the **question** asks "is this possible?" but OP seems to **expect** a full solution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't seem too hard.

```
$ ./a.out
Caught signal at 0x400966: Segmentation fault
Segmentation fault
$ GDB_COMM=:1024 ./a.out
Caught signal at 0x400966: Segmentation fault
Attached; pid = 2369
Listening on port 1024
```

```
$ gdb ./a.out
Reading symbols from /home/me/a.out...done.
(gdb) target remote :1024
Remote debugging using :1024
```

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static char *gdb_comm;
static void segv_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc) {
    pid_t child;
    char msg[84], pid[20];
    char *const argv[] = {"gdbserver", gdb_comm, "--attach", pid, NULL};
    sprintf(msg, "Caught signal at %p", si->si_addr);
    psignal(si->si_signo, msg);
    if (gdb_comm && *gdb_comm) {
        switch ((child = fork())) {
        case 0:
            sprintf(pid, "%ld", (long)getppid());
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("Failed to start gdbserver");
            _exit(-1);
        case -1:
            perror("failed to fork");
        default:
            waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static struct sigaction segv_action = {
        .sa_sigaction = segv_handler,
        .sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_SIGINFO,
    };
    gdb_comm = getenv("GDB_COMM");
    sigaction(SIGILL, &segv_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &segv_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &segv_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &segv_action, NULL);
    *(int *)main = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I was expected as an answer.  
I think I've questioned that "if someone had integrated libsegfault.so and gdbserver".  
I wanted a reason why this was not done yet, or a correct (adequate) integration between libsegfault.so and gdbserver.  
  
Sorry for my question for not being detailed enough, but the requirements are:  
1. Being able to plugin by LD_PRELOAD to any program
2. The program may be a multithreaded program
3. The program may link to a library that contain main function

Comment: This is just a proof-of-concept, to demonstrate that I do not believe there are any significant obstacles to implementing this.  It should not be difficult to adapt the ideas to your specifications, and all the syscalls needed here are async-safe, so it should be okay in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: Well, I think this is obvious.
I thought there might be some other technical or political problem to put them together in glibc.

Comment: Almost year passed, and nobody answers a reason, so this might be just be possible without any problem, thank you very much anyway.